# Grab multiple input radio values and Submit to PHP script

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

well today I want to learn how to grab multiple input type button value compare to original value and last submit to php script! How can I do that with Jquery?

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="leftDiv" class="container"> 
<form action="" method="get"> 
    <fieldset>
        <p>Something 0</p>

        <lable>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group0" value="1" >

        <lable>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group0" value="0" >

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <p>Something 1</p>

        <lable>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group1" value="1" >

        <lable>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group1" value="0" >

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <p>Something 2</p>

        <lable>Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group2" value="1" >

        <lable>No</label>
        <input type="radio" name="Group2" value="0" >

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>  
        <input type="submit" name="update" class="button" value="Submit"> 
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the above values are generated by php script (can be 1 or 100)

Comment: Can you be more elaborate or atleast show us an example?

Comment: You need to expand your question with more detail e.g., add the HTML you are using for the radio buttons, write out some pseudo code for what you want to achieve, explain what input your PHP script expects, etc.

Comment: the inputs need diffrent names

Comment: The input has the same number because bellongs to the same group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest method is actually to set the correct values as selected in the HTML and tie a .onChange event to them. otherwise, have a hidden field with the original value, and onChange compare them like this

```
   //a hidden input field with the original value
    <input type='hidden' id='Group0' value='0'/>
    // a set of radio fields that reference the original field we will be comparing with in their 'rel' attribute for easy jQuery selection
    Off<input type='radio' name='Group0' rel='#Group0' class='compareOnChane' value=0/><br/>
    On <input type='radio' name='Group0' rel='#Group0' class='compareOnChane' value=1/>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.compareOnChange').live('change',function(){
         if($($(this).attr('rel')).val()!=$(this).val(){
          //the value currently is different than the original value, fire our action
         }

       });

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good tutorial that will teach you the basics of this:

http://trevordavis.net/blog/ajax-forms-with-jquery

You can get the values of the radio buttons in a JSON like so:

```
var radios = {};
$('input[type="radio"]').each(function() {
  radios[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
});
```

Comment: ok, so radios is the array that will store all the data right? let's say that I will have more than one div with radio buttons should a refere this specific div, how can I do it? So after store all the values how can I send it to php?

Comment: var radios does store all the data, as a JSON. At the moment it gets the data for all radio buttons on the page. To only do it for the checked ones you'll need to add the :checked selector, and to only do it for some (in a div), you'll put the div ID first: $('#divID input[type="radio"]:checked'). To send that data to php you need to read through the tutorial I linked to. There's no point me repeating it here.

Comment: I first read and completed that tutorial in an hour. It's really good, well worth it. It will summarize things for you better than a lot of places.